# Crash "empty-list String!" using Swagger client

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile, request, swagger

Logs:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  Kanopy PROD                    0x57000 ActivationScenariogetAutoLoginIfNeeded empty-list String! (ActivationScenario.swift:254)
1  libswiftFoundation.dylib       0x10d30c0 URL.init(string : String) -> URL? (__hidden#6745_)
2  Kanopy PROD                    0x57b34 ActivationScenariogetAutoLoginIfNeeded empty-list String! (ActivationScenario.swift)
3  Kanopy PROD                    0x1e9fc8 AuthServicegetAutologinUrl empty-list String!userID first-element-marker userIDdestinationuserID (AuthService.swift:228)
4  Kanopy PROD                    0x57b98 AuthServicegetAutologinUrl empty-list String!userID first-element-marker userIDdestinationuserID (ActivationScenario.swift)
5  Kanopy PROD                    0xa7c40 RequestServicegetAutologinUrl empty-list String!userID first-element-marker userIDdestinationuserID (RequestService.swift:1186)
6  Kanopy PROD                    0xa5424 RequestServicegetVideoItem empty-list String!videoID first-element-marker (ItemModel) -> ()completion empty-list completion + 1250340
7  Kanopy PROD                    0x92764 @callee_owned (@owned SWGVideoList?, @owned Error?) -> ()Error (RequestService.swift)
8  SwaggerClient                  0xa70d01 __100-[SWGAuthApi usersUserIdAutologinGetWithUserId:authorization:destination:hashtag:completionHandler:]_block_invoke (SWGAuthApi.m:928)
9  SwaggerClient                  0xa6b69d __178-[SWGApiClient requestWithPath:method:pathParams:queryParams:formParams:files:body:headerParams:authSettings:requestContentType:responseContentType:responseType:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.184 (SWGApiClient.m:242)
10 SwaggerClient                  0xa6a21f __56-[SWGApiClient taskWithCompletionBlock:completionBlock:]_block_invoke (SWGApiClient.m:106)
11 Kanopy PROD                    0x1bfb50 URLResponse empty-list  (SWGApiClientExt.swift)
12 Kanopy PROD                    0x1bfecc SWGApiClient.dataTask(with : URLRequest, completionHandler : (URLResponse, Any?, Error?) -> ()?) -> URLSessionDataTask empty-list URLResponse first-element-marker Error (SWGApiClientExt.swift:26)
13 Kanopy PROD                    0x1bf7c4 SWGApiClient.dataTask(with : URLRequest, completionHandler : (URLResponse, Any?, Error?) -> ()?) -> URLSessionDataTask empty-list URLResponse first-element-marker Error (SWGApiClientExt.swift)
14 Kanopy PROD                    0x1bf87c @callee_owned (@owned URLResponse, @in Any?, @owned Error?) -> ()URLResponse empty-list  (SWGApiClientExt.swift)
15 AFNetworking                   0x48bb75 __72-[AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:]_block_invoke_2.150 (AFURLSessionManager.m:308)
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x1a5cd797 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x1a5cd783 _dispatch_client_callout + 22
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x1a5d1b15 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 406
19 CoreFoundation                 0x1aebbd69 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
20 CoreFoundation                 0x1aeb9e19 __CFRunLoopRun + 848
21 CoreFoundation                 0x1ae0d1af CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
22 CoreFoundation                 0x1ae0cfd1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
23 GraphicsServices               0x1c5b7b41 GSEventRunModal + 80
24 UIKit                          0x2018fa53 UIApplicationMain + 150
25 Kanopy PROD                    0x1810c main (LogExt.swift:20)
26 libdyld.dylib                  0x1a5fa4eb start + 2
```

I'm using the Swagger client (Objective-C) in the application.
I do not understand what an " empty-list String!" error.
I checked all the required fields against nil for the request.

Also, in this case, the application can send many requests the same time.